# Solve 'x' in this equation when passed variables using C#

Tags: math

I want to create a C# method that solves 'x' for the equation below when it is passed with value of a, b, c, d, and e.

```
0 = (a)(x) + (1-x) [(b)(c)-(d)(e)]
```

I'm not very mathematically inclined so I don't even know how to get started using something like [Math.Net](https://www.mathdotnet.com/) from looking at the documentation.

Can someone please help or point me to an example?

Comment: Are you actually looking for some way to use this for arbitrary equations passed in somehow? Because if the equation is fixed, you can just rewrite it in terms of x (by hand), and then the function is trivial.

Comment: Just the fixed equation.  I don't know how to rewrite it.  I'm rubbish at maths :(

Comment: Then your question is not about programming, it's about algebra. That's fine, plenty of people struggle with it, but it's not really on-topic for this site. I suggest you find some algebra tutorials, or see if you know someone who could help you with it in exchange for a drink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, simplify equation in terms of x

```
0 = (a)(x) + (1-x) [(b)(c)-(d)(e)]
0 = (a)(x) + [(b)(c)-(d)(e)] - [(b)(c)-(d)(e)](x)
0 = (a)(x) - [(b)(c)-(d)(e)](x) + [(b)(c)-(d)(e)]
0 = { (a) - [(b)(c)-(d)(e)] } (x) + [(b)(c)-(d)(e)]
0 = [(a) - (b)(c) + (d)(e)](x) + [(b)(c)-(d)(e)]
- [(b)(c)-(d)(e)] = [(a) - (b)(c) + (d)(e)](x)
[(d)(e)-(b)(c)] = [(a) - (b)(c) + (d)(e)](x)
[(d)(e)-(b)(c)] / [(a) - (b)(c) + (d)(e)] = (x)
(x) = [(d)(e)-(b)(c)] / [(a) - (b)(c) + (d)(e)]
```

```
public static float solveForX(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
        return (d*e - b*c)/ (a- b*c + d*e);
    }
```

Comment: Mind: if a-bc+de = 0 , you'll get NaN!

Answer (score 1):

As the comment mentions, this can be simplified

```
0 = ax + (1-x)(bc - de)
0 = ax + (bc - de) - x(bc - de)
0 = x(a - (bc - de)) + (bc - de)
-(bc - de) = x(a - (bc - de))
(de - bc) = x(a - bc + de)
x = (de - bc) / (a - bc + de)
```

That last line works provided a - bc + de is not zero. If it is zero, then look at the nextto last line. We find that any value for x works if de - bc = 0; otherwise, no value for x makes the equation true. In summary:

```
If a - bc + de = 0 then
    if de - bc = 0 then
        print "any value of x works"
    else
        print "no value of x works"
else
    print (de - bc) / (a - bc + de)
```

Something like that.